# How do I fetch a webpage with node-fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, node-fetch

The following code:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
;(async function fn() {
  const response = await fetch('https://learnitmyway.com/learning-material-software-development/')
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log({ data })
})()
```

results in: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: HTML is not JSON so json() throws an error.

Comment: That is why we had documentation to review.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text or https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-body-text%E2%91%A0

Comment: From my point of view it can't be expected that every developer knows where to find this in documentation, especially not in a spec.

Comment: You learn.... that is how it works. 22 years ago when I started, I had to look at books and pray I found it. It is in the specification. That is the second link!

Comment: I agree that you can learn it and I also believe that Stack Overflow is here to speed up the process. From my point of view it's not fair to assume that all developers know how to understand documentation or a spec

Comment: I think it's fair to assume that people who have this problem in the future may not have understood the documentation.

Comment: SO should generally be used as a last resort after you've exhausted all the other options. Like @epascarello I started around 20 years ago and we didn't have the wealth of documentation that we have now. If you don't understand your code, and haven't studied what's wrong with it, or looked at some documentation, "speeding up the process" does nothing to increase your knowledge of the language. All we can do is point you to the documentation that you didn't read.

Comment: I think it's fairly common for people to get stuck and use Stack Overflow without finding their answer in the documentation, which is why I thought the question was worth posting.

Comment: So the question remains why you think that you'd be getting JSON as a response.

Comment: Let's not go off topic. From my point of view, it doesn't matter how I came to the mistake.

I think this answer sums up my thoughts quite well https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299411/5955911

Answer (score -3):

Replace `json` with `text` as follows:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
;(async function fn() {
  const response = await fetch('https://learnitmyway.com/learning-material-software-development/')
  const data = await response.text()
  console.log({ data })
})()
```